# sizeof operator in c

Tags: c

I have a question regarding this code:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(""));
}
```

It prints `1`, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its the string containing the `\0` (Null) character, which has `1 Byte` size.

Answer (score 4):

`""` = `\0` (Null character). Which is 1 byte. Therefore the size of it is 1.

Answer (score 4):

I interpreted the author's question to mean why 1 is printed instead of 4 or 8 (pointer size), not why is the size of a string == number consecutive non-zero bytes plus 1.

```
main(){printf("%d", sizeof((const char *)""));}
```

The output of the above program is 8 (pointer size on my machine). In this case, the compiler treats "" as it would be treated in a case like this: { const char *pointer = ""; }, not like this { char c[] = ""; }. (If you're familiar with x86 asm, its essentially lea vs. mov) The latter reserves 1 byte for a "buffer" on the stack, initialized to '\0'.

Answer (score 2):

The string literal `""` is of type `char[1]` (a `char` array of one element, the NUL byte), not as `char*`/`const char*`.  Therefore `sizeof` yields the size of the array, which is 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

"" == empty string or null terminated pointer to character.

It prints 1 because of the null terminator.

i.e.

"" really equals  '\0'

Comment: `"\0"` however has *two* null terminators, and a size of 2.

Comment: No, '\0' != "\0".  One is a character the other is a char*

Answer (score 0):

In C, `sizeof` operator returns the size of a datatype in a number of bytes. In your case, an empty "" costs you 1 byte, and therefore it returns value 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your program actually has undefined behavior because `%d` is not a valid format specifier for `size_t` expressions. You should use `%zu` or else cast the result of `sizeof` down to `int`. Otherwise the existing answers are okay.